# Do I pay for the started hour when my spot instance is terminated by AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, price, amazon-ec2-spot-market

Assumed I am using a Linux spot instance, which was terminated after 30 minutes by AWS, due to increased Spot Market prices.

Before Oktober 2017 the instances were charged per hour, and the instance wouldnt have been charged for the started hour.
See: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot/pricing/

> “With Spot instances, you will never be charged more than the maximum
>   price you specified.  While your instance runs, you are charged the
>   Spot price that is in effect for that period.  If the Spot price
>   exceeds your specified price, your instance will receive a two-minute
>   notification before it is terminated, and you **will not be charged for**
>   **the partial hour** that your instance has run.”

Now, since Oktober 2017 the instances are charged per second.
See https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-per-second-billing-for-ec2-instances-and-ebs-volumes/

> List prices and **Spot Market prices** are **still listed on a per-hour**
>   **basis, but bills are calculated down to the second**, as is Reserved
>   Instance usage (you can launch, use, and terminate multiple instances
>   within an hour and get the Reserved Instance Benefit for all of the
>   instances).

**Question** 
Does it mean, that one would pay for the 30 Minutes usage of the Spot instance, even if it was terminated?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you are running an **Amazon Linux Spot instance** under the new per-second charging model:

- If AWS terminates your instance **in the first hour**, there is no charge
- If AWS terminates your instance **after the first hour**, you will be charged for the actual time that the instance was running (down to the second)

From [Spot Instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-spot-instances.html):

> At the start of each instance hour, you are charged based on the Spot price. If Amazon EC2 terminates your Spot Instance in the *first* instance hour because the Spot price exceeded your bid, you are **not charged for the partial hour of usage**. If Amazon EC2 terminates your Spot Instance in any subsequent hour, you are **charged for your usage to the nearest second**. If you terminate your Spot Instance in the middle of an instance hour—be it the first or any subsequent hour—you are charged for your usage rounded to the nearest second.

**UPDATE (2019):** The above information has now disappeared from the documentation, so things might have changed.

Comment: And for the sake of completeness "There is a 1 minute minimum charge per-instance".

Comment: @Tanbouz note that this shouldn't apply to an instance that is terminated by AWS -- only to instances terminated by the user.

Comment: hello john, do you have some links to the aws documentation to confirm your sayings?

Comment: Reference added.

Comment: What if the user terminates it (for example, I use Packer). Am I being billed for the entire hour at spot price? Or am I being billed for the 10 minutes that I use? From the above excerpt from the docs it reads as if i should be charged 10min and however many seconds but when I look at the savings dashboard it appears like it takes whole hours into account only.

Comment: AWS just rephrase that in another place. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-interruptions.html#billing-for-interrupted-spot-instances